# Decoupling capacitors in MCUs

Tags: microcontroller, capacitor

This is related to decoupling capacitors on Vcc pins of MCUs. Most of my designs I usually put a sprinkling of a 10pf,10nF and 1uf or so to filter out any differential noise, and other noises on the very high,median and low frequency ranges. It has worked always. No doubts and is quite recommended by many vendors and also on their eval boards they have the same values(more or less).

But, is there a method to this madness. I was going through a rad hard MCU datasheet (for academic purpose) and stumbled on a line. The link is given below - [image: Link]

So, there is a relation between the peripheral switching frequency and the value of the capacitor. Is it so ?
If so, is the only factor the peripheral frequency or would other factors play in this ?

Comment: Have a look at the caps datasheets and their impedance vs. frequency.

Comment: There can be [a lot of method](http://www.ewh.ieee.org/r4/se_michigan/emcs/DL-ARCH-decoupling3.pdf) to this madness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick answer: transient currents are the reason for decoupling capacitors

A device with a high current demand will draw high current, and so suffer a large voltage drop in the conductors to the device. To over come this, a small, low impedance voltage store is put next to the device drawing the current.

If a device is switching loads at a set frequency, than the frequency of this switching will be what the decoupling will be tuned to cope with. However it is extremely rare to find a device with only one switching frequency, hence you are left with a range of frequencies to give a supply to, and so a range of capacitance is required.

Some other reasons to add decoupling capacitors (no doubt there are others):

- Improve EMC performance by reducing the current spikes and the distance the currents flow over
- Improve immunity to ripple on the supply lines (including transient and surges)

I recommend reading Respawned Fluff's link too.

Answer (score 3):

Analog devices has a great app note discussing, not only the value, but capacitor type, as well as component placement. http://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-101.pdf

To your questions... Small capacitors react faster to high freq than multiple large ones would in series. From this perspective, having 3 caps in parallel (10pf,10nF and 1uF) might look like you have an equivalent  large cap of 1.001001 uF, you essentially have 3 lowpass filters of 3 different freqs...

Also, I do a lot with instrumentation amps and brush motors so I often use ferrite beads, with 1k impedance around 10kHz, in series to the power pin.